# Matlab class constructor without initializing properties

Tags: matlab, class

Similar to C++ where we can define a constructor without initialization, can we do it in Matlab classdef? I tried but it complains that "Test is already defined", meaning I can't define two functions with the same name.

```
classdef Test
    properties
        id;
    end
    methods
        %constructor without initialization
        function obj = Test
        end

        %constructor with initialization
        function obj = Test(x)
            obj.id = x;
            end
        end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor definition can specify an input argument and it doesn't technically have to be passed by the user. You can use `exist` with the input variable name to determine if an input was provided and only assign the property value if an input is provided.

```
classdef Test
    properties
        id;
    end

    methods
        function obj = Test(x)
            if exist('x', 'var')
                obj.id = x;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: thank you. what id there are more than one propoerties, say Test(x,y) how to modify exist() ?

Comment: @daydayup You can look at the docs for `exist`, but you can add another `if exist('y', 'var')` for `y`

Comment: Use "exist" if you need x and y to be present or absent independently. Otherwise check out nargin function which gives you number of input arguments.